# Casting Error related to XmlBeanFactory

Tags: java, spring

When trying to run the Junit Test I got this error. This line :

```
     AppConfig.getGatewayConfigurations().getURL();
```

is working fine on some places. Also I have no problem related to the path of XML File. And the class GatewayConfigurations is built well and its attributes assigned well in bean configuration file !

Here is the trace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory cannot be cast to com.me.vpc.configurations.GatewayConfigurations
at com.me.vpc.configurations.AppConfig.getGatewayConfigurations(AppConfig.java:26)
at com.me.vpc.test.PaymentQueryStringBuilderThirdPartyTest.buildQueryStringTest(PaymentQueryStringBuilderThirdPartyTest.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTestMethod(MethodRoadie.java:98)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:79)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:87)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:77)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

PaymentQueryStringBuilderThirdPartyTest Class

```
package com.me.vpc.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.me.vpc.common.PaymentQueryStringBuilderThirdParty;
import com.me.vpc.configurations.AppConfig;


 public class PaymentQueryStringBuilderThirdPartyTest {

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private Map parameters;

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    parameters = new HashMap();

    parameters.put("vpc_Merchant", "MER123");
    parameters.put("vpc_OrderInfo", "A48cvE28");
    parameters.put("vpc_Amount", "2995");
}

@Test
public void buildQueryStringTest() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    String URL = AppConfig.getGatewayConfigurations().getURL();

    String expectedQueryString = URL + "?vpc_Merchant=MER123&vpc_OrderInfo=A48cvE28&vpc_Amount=2995";

    assertEquals(expectedQueryString, PaymentQueryStringBuilderThirdParty.buildQueryString(parameters));
}

}
```

AppConfig Class

```
public class AppConfig {

/**
 * Default xml configurations file
 */
private final static String APP_CONFIG_FILE = "vpc-configurations.xml";

/**
 * Load gateway configurations
 * @return GatwayConfigurations object
 */
public static GatewayConfigurations getGatewayConfigurations(){

    return (GatewayConfigurations)getBeans();
}

/**
 * Get the desired configuration bean
 * @param beanName
 * @return BeanFactory object
 */
private static BeanFactory getBeans()
{
    return new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource(APP_CONFIG_FILE));
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the API for [XmlBeanFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/XmlBeanFactory.html), I can't see how it could be cast to `com.me.vpc.configurations.GatewayConfigurations` (not surprisingly because you have created that class / interface).

`getBeans()` returns a `XmlBeanFactory`, and `getGatewayConfigurations()` casts that to `GatewayConfigurations`. This will never work.